# Method Eat used in the class Lion. How can I set the value of eaten thing (living thing) as dead?

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, interface

Eat Method in the Interface IAnimal in the AnimalWorld has a fuction in the class Lion. When an animal (Lion) eats a Living thing, the leaving thing dies.

**ILIVING**

```
namespace AnimalWorld
{
    public interface ILiving
    {
        Status LifeStatus
        {
            get; set;
        }

        Status GetLifeStatus();


    }
}
```

**IANIMALS**

```
namespace AnimalWorld
{
    public interface IAnimals : ILiving
    {
        // List<IAnimals> Breed(string babyName);
        string Name { get; set; }
        IAnimals Breed(string babyName);

        int Legs { get; }

        void Eat(ILiving food);

    }
}
```

**LION**

```
namespace AnimalWorld
{
    public class Lion : IAnimals
    {

        public Lion(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public Lion()
        {
        }

        public Status LifeStatus { get; set; }

        public Status GetLifeStatus()
        {
            return Status.Alive;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IAnimals Breed(string babyName)
        {
            var baby = new Lion(babyName);
            return baby;
        }

        public int Legs
        {
            get { return 4; }
        }


        public void Eat(ILiving food)
        {
            return food;
        }
    }
}
```

**PROGRAM**

```
namespace AnimalWorld
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var l = new Lion("first lion");

            var firstBabyL = l.Breed("first baby lion");
            var secondBabyL = l.Breed("second baby lion");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: in `Eat()` : `food.LifeStatus = Status.Dead` or whatever how is written that enum (assuming it's an enum)

Comment: By the way, `GetLifeStatus()` makes no sense, because 1) looks like a lion can't die (anways returns `Status.Alive`), 2) `Status LifeStatus` has already a public getter

Comment: Thanks guys. I should add there is an enum for life status.namespace AnimalWorld
{
    public enum Status
    {
        Alive,
        Dead
    }
} ``

Comment: Your `Breed`-method should probably be generic. A `Lion` probably does not breed a `Cangaroo`, does it? Furthermore you should name your interface singular: `IAnimal`, unless you truely mean **all** animals that exist by a single instance of that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `LifeStatus` is a public property, it can be set from the Lion's `Eat()` method.

```
public void Eat(ILiving food)
{
    food.LifeStatus = LifeStatus.Dead;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a method `Die`:

```cs
    public interface ILiving
    {
        Status LifeStatus
        {
            get; set;
        }

        Status GetLifeStatus();

        void Die();
    }
```

Used as:

```cs
public class Lion : IAnimals
{
    //...
    void Die()
    {
        LifeStatus = Status.Dead;
    }
    //....
}
```

If I am getting this right, what you probably need as an answer is to **keep setters private and provide methods that express the behavior of your classes/interfaces instead**.

Imagine LifeStatus being arbitrarily set at various positions all over your code, and suddenly, *dying* acquires a different meaning for your `IAnimals`. You will have to chase down all places where it has been set. Instead, if you have a method, you can do whatever you wish in the method, and all places where it has been invoked will not have to be changed in any way. You will "enforce" the new meaning directly inside the class.

Now, why *dying* might change meaning, is a different story...

Comment: In my answer I tried to stick as close to the OP's code as possible, but I agree that it would be a good idea to make LifeStatus private and make a method like "Die" or "Kill" (since the ILiving will not be calling it itself).

Comment: @jasonmchoe Yes, your answer is, technically, the shortest clean change to the current posted model that achieves what is asked. I only added the extra information because the example seems to be too contrived and I got the feeling that the problem is not how to achieve what is asked in the specific design, rather a slight confusion about how this problem should be tackled in general.